# Referencing a previous batch operation in Neo4J's Rest API, sometimes results in a 404 - Not Found

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4J's Batch API to aggregate rest calls and POST to the /batch API. As per the docs (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-refer-to-items-created-earlier-in-the-same-batch-job), I'm attempting to refer to previous operations in the batch by using the notation {[JOB ID]}.

In a couple of environments, POST operations to create a new Node are successful, with references to that operation (e.g. to create a relationship), but in another environment a 404 - Not Found error is returned.

For a very simple example (borrowing from the docs), assuming there is already a node created that I'm creating a relationship *FROM*:

```
[{
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/node",
  "id" : 0,
  "body" : {
    "name" : "bob"
  }
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/node",
  "id" : 1,
  "body" : {
    "age" : 12
  }
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/node/1234/relationships",
  "id" : 2,
  "body" : {
    "to" : "{1}",
    "data" : {
      "since" : "2010"
    },
    "type" : "KNOWS"
  }
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/index/relationship/my_rels",
  "id" : 3,
  "body" : {
    "key" : "since",
    "value" : "2010",
    "uri" : "{3}"
  }
} ]
```

Job, with id #2, will result in the 404 - Not Found, in regard to the Node being created at Job #1.

Considering that there are multiple environments (local and dev) in which this works without issue, is there something on the Neo4J server, or the client settings for the environment that might be causing this issue? Alternatively, is there a slowness in a cache that could be delaying the creation within the transaction? (I don't understand the internals well, so I'm guessing at what I should be asking for.)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the Cypher endpoint for this type of requests, and post something like:

```
MATCH (other)
WHERE id(other) = 1234
WITH other
CREATE ({name:'Bob'})-[:KNOWS]->(other)
```

Against the Cypher REST endpoint or the transactional endpoint for bigger transactions at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but the endpoint of the relationship has yet to be created. This looks like it assumes to be already created before the batch is invoked.

Comment: The answer is moot, unfortunately. I'm not finding that I can repeat this from anywhere other than the application creating and submitting the batch in the specific environment. I even tried using curl and the batch commands from a file, and it works. I don't really want to delete the question, but this doesn't really answer my question. Will figure out in a few hours what I want to do here, and ask another more specific question regarding my issue. Thanks anyway!